# How to find where my PATH variable is being generated and how to edit it in Mac OSX Terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, path

Currently I am in Mac OSX and when I try to find what my PATH is via Terminal, I get:

```
> echo $PATH
/Users/User1/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/usr/local
/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:
/Library/TeX/texbin:/opt/X11/bin:
/Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS
```

I would like to remove google-cloud-sdk, wireshark, and tex from PATH, but have no idea how to do it. When I look inside my `etc/profile` file, none of these apps are listed. Is there a way to clean up by $PATH? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found the Wireshark path file in :

`/etc/paths.d/`

Comment: Look at `/etc/profile`, OS X uses `path_helper` to set the path based on the files in `/etc/paths.d`. Hence, removing from `/etc/paths.d` works.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your home directory. If you open a fresh Terminal window/session, this will probably have you in your home directory.

Type,

`ls -al`

This should give you a list of the files in your home directory, including invisible files. Check there is a file called .bash_profile. The "." means it is an invisible file.

If that exists (as it should) type:

`nano .bash_profile`

This will open this file in the text editor program called "nano". In this file you should find statements like:

`export PATH="/Library/Frameworks ....`

There should be similar PATH statement for the options you want to remove.

Delete those lines and then exit nano by ^O for writing out, and you need to print Y to save. Then ^X to exit nano.